# Are Hera Syndulla and Kanan Jarrus in love?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, love

Watching the interactions between Hera and Kanan - especially when they are alone - I get a weird vibe that there is more to their relationship than just close friends and fellow rebels. It could be just me, maybe it's really just a boring normal friendship - I don't really have experience in this field. I just find it intriguing that Hera and Kanan open up to each other in ways they don't to others, not even Ahsoka - not just with regards to the secrets they hold inside them, but also a hidden side of their selves altogether.

Of course, Jedi cannot have that kind of relationships, but that does not mean they are not liable to experiencing the same underlying emotions - it won't be the first time, after all.

**Is there any *romantic attraction* at play here, either reciprocal or just one-sided?**

Comment: Anything’s possible...

Comment: "Is there any possibility that romantic attraction exists between Kanan and Hera, regardless of whether it is one-sided or _consensual_, whether they are aware of it or not?" I don't think _consensual_ is the word you meant to put there, it doesn't makes sense. :/

Comment: @RedCaio - Yeah, not the best choice of words. "*Non-consensual*" carries a lot of overtones that I don't think were intended. "*One-sided*" or "*unreciprocated*" seem far closer to what the OP wanted.

Comment: friends with benefits ?

Comment: I felt that my answer on this one was pretty comprehensive, with multiple relevant sources. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 10):

The implication is that their relationship status is pretty well established. They appear to be in a committed monogamous relationship, albeit one they keep almost totally hidden from the rest of the crew and us, the audience. There's also a certain element of [not really wanting to admit to each other](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Adw6BsiVTDg&feature=youtu.be&t=17s) how close they've gotten. Hera also uses her close relationship with Kanan to manipulate him (emotionally) into doing things her way, especially when she calls him "love".

---

This dialogue from "[A New Dawn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_New_Dawn)" (before the start of Rebels) strongly implies that while Hera is open to flirtation, she's really not interested in maintaining a serious relationship.

> He obviously liked her starship, she could see as he walked around it.
>   That was good. He was also smitten with her, she could tell—and she
>   was all right with that, too. She didn’t want to tell him that her war
>   had already begun, and that in war, there was no time for anything
>   else. He would probably understand that eventually.

With that in mind, in the short "[The Machine in the Ghost](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Machine_in_the_Ghost)", they're **clearly about to kiss** when interrupted by Chopper. After a brief bit of banter, they give him a bunch of chores to do ***elsewhere on the ship***, the metaphorical equivalent of giving him $10 to bugger off to the cinema.

And in the [Star Wars: Rebels - Rise of the Rebels](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rise_of_the_Rebels) novel, we have the following internal voice from Hera's perspective:

> There was nothing but static. If the TIE’s blasts had somehow hit the
>   turret and she’d lost Kanan, she didn’t know what she’d do. **Kanan
>   Jarrus was more than a friend or a colleague. The human meant the
>   world to her—although she’d never admit it to him.**

and [this quote](http://comicbook.com/2015/03/25/mtfbwy-9-vanessa-hera-marshall-talks-star-wars-rebels-season-1-h/) from Hera's character actor Vanessa Marshall shows that the relationship is a lot deeper than even she's been told!

> So I don’t see much schmaltzy romance, on the page. When I watch the
>   episodes and I’ve seen some gestures and body language that wasn’t
>   described in the script, as far as I recall, I thought, “woah, wait a
>   minute!” I remember being at Star Wars Weekends and they played that
>   initial short where the two of them are bickering and Chopper is going
>   between them. At the end, they sort of come together, and **I remember
>   sitting there watching it, going “hey now! What was that?”** Everyone
>   was asking me, and I had no idea! I didn’t get a sense of that while
>   reading it or recording it! **So it’s interesting to me to allow what
>   may happen in the animation, a caress or a look, that indicates a
>   deeper connection.**

---

> And of course, the final season makes it abundantly clear. [They kiss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gE2TqxTiu4g), she tells him that she's in love with him and they ultimately [have a child together](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukruJtYvKmM)

Comment: This is good but could do with a little updating now that there is physical proof of romantic (or at least physical) attraction

Comment: @JeremyFrench  - I've updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I'd always assumed that they were in a full de facto relationship, but because Rebels was made for a younger audience the writers wanted to keep it relatively PG. There is something about their body language when they're together. Here's one example:

[image: Space Married]
<sub>(source: [tumblr.com](http://65.media.tumblr.com/3a37f32a52b30e7898d720634b6bcd41/tumblr_inline_o043seVVwd1rzu6y7_500.jpg))</sub>  .

A man and a woman just don't get in each other's personal space like that unless they've been given permission. Although nothing is ever said, in dialogue, most older viewers pick up on the body language and draw the inevitable conclusion.

So, there's probably some smooching and kanoodling going on, but it's all happening behind closed doors. And the kiddies notwithstanding, if they're in an established relationship there probably isn't much to be gained (in a dramatic sense) from showing the romantic stuff anyway.

Comment: I think you’re probably right (or close to it). But could you provide any evidence that this is the case, whether from the show or elsewhere? That would greatly help this answer.

Comment: They way they look at each other and in each other's personal space. [Here's one example](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-mCHET_0R60Q/VsZ2yTLidaI/AAAAAAAAASQ/Dy5SbCGxPT4/s1600/Space-Married.jpg), but I'm sure there are more.

Comment: Or [try this](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-YFklFnGGNXw/VsZ3kWBpGcI/AAAAAAAAASY/HLjJCJ8GfUY/s1600/hera%2Band%2Bkanan.png).

Comment: [And other](http://65.media.tumblr.com/3a37f32a52b30e7898d720634b6bcd41/tumblr_inline_o043seVVwd1rzu6y7_500.jpg). A man and a woman just don't get in each other's personal space like that unless they've been given permission. Although nothing is ever said, in dialogue, most older viewers pick up on the body language and are left with the inevitable conclusion.

Comment: That seems persuasive, and distinct from the other answer. Could you edit some of this into your answer?

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score -1):

Welp Hera does refer to Kanan as "my love" in one of the last two episodes of the current season (the season with the episode "twin suns") so unless this is a figure of speech that I've never heard of seems fairly indicative of a relationship.

Comment: Can you provide any sources for your answer? It is recommended that you support your answer with as much evidence to show proof your answer is valid and not just an assumption you've made.

Comment: I believe she addresses him as "love", not "my love".

Answer (score -2):

From part 2 of the Season Three finale:

> WHOOSHING FADES) (EXPLOSIONS STOP) (CRACKLING) It held! It held!
> (LAUGHING) (COMLINK BEEPING)
>
> **Hera:** *Kanan? Kanan, do you copy?*
>
> **KANAN:** (GROANS) *I'm gettin' the feeling Thrawn's actually trying to kill us this time.*
>
> **Hera:** *Oh, that is only funny because you're still alive. Now, **please, come home, love.***

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Some people will address someone they are fond of as "love," regardless of whether they are "in love."

Comment: Hera uses 'love' and  other endearments exclusively with Kanan (though less so in season 3 until the finale). Also, even with not having his padawan for a  bunkie, he doesn't spend a lot of time there late at night (Twin suns) *wink* Take it as you will...